# GA to GBQ data streaming timing?

Tags: google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am asking this question as I didn't receive reply on Google Forum nor from the GCP Support team.

I have linked the product Google BigQuery (GBQ) to the Google Analytics (GA) for a view ID, which is fetching all the data from GA to GBQ dataset under two views in respective tables as :

[image]

I have two questions on Intraday Views:

1. Why current day table is not populated in GBQ? Even GBQ doesn't support Real time data from GA, at least they should provide delayed data within a buffer of some hours.
2. Does GBQ have a fixed timing to update the Intraday table trice in a day?

How can I tackle these scenarios?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're asking exactly, but have a read here. Intraday tables are updated every 8 hours: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related

Comment: If your tables are updated  three times a day then you are not using streaming export.

Comment: @GrahamPolley hey I am trying to take updated data out of the intraday table. but there is no any last modified field to use the where condition on it. Any Idea?

Comment: @EikePierstorff If I Adjust the Link from Export 3 tiimes to Immediately this ga_realtime_sessions_ table will be available . but Is there any Last_modified field in the schema to put a where condition on it?

Answer (score 1):

ad Q1: There is real-time streaming for GA export: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7430726?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089

ad Q2: From my experience, this varies - you can monitor both:

- table creation using meta-tables: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#tables-meta-table
- export logs (which should be filtered for `protopayload_auditlog.authenticationInfo.principalEmail = "analytics-processing-dev@system.gserviceaccount.com"`) to BigQuery and analyze them: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/

Comment: yeah @Martin  Thanks for the Export Logging part of your Answer. But I have Solved My Problem with __Table__ query. Thanks Again